# Protractor: Continue with test if element is not displayed

Tags: jasmine, protractor, try-catch

Using protractor, I'm testing if copied files,if there are any, are listed when clicking on double files icon. So i want to create test in which I will check for double files icon and click on it and expect that list is opened. But, if there are no double files icon, i want to log message.

I've tried if/else and try/catch
isDisplayed(), ispresent(), (in)visibilityOf() 
and always same outcome: If element is displayed, test pass. 
If element is not displayed test fails

```
it('should check if assignment has double files', () => {
    try {
        element.dubleFilesIcon.isDisplayed().then(function() {
            console.log('There ARE double files for this assignment!!!');
            assignmentHeader.doubleFiles();
            expect(element.doubleFilesindicator.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        }, function(err) {
            console.error('error' + err);
            throw err;
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('There ARE NO double files for this assignment!!!');
        expect(element.doubleFilesindicator).toBe(false);
    }
});
```

This is error:
1) Asignment header test cases should check if assignment has double files
  - Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, '')

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what

Answer (score 0):

`isDisplayed()` is used for when you know the element is present in the DOM. You need to check for its presence first with `isPresent()`

```
element.dubleFilesIcon.isPresent().then(function() {
    console.log('There ARE double files for this assignment!!!');
    assignmentHeader.doubleFiles();
    expect(element.doubleFilesindicator.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
});
```

Additionally, if you want the test to fail if its not present/displayed, you can use this:

```
it('should check if assignment has double files', (done) => {
    element.dubleFilesIcon.isPresent().then(function(present) {
        if (present) {
            console.log('There ARE double files for this assignment!!!');
            assignmentHeader.doubleFiles();
            expect(element.doubleFilesindicator.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
            done();
        } else {
            // Here I think you want to test if dubleFilesIcon is NOT present
            // Then expect the files indicator not to be present, which is a bit 
            // redundant. But anyway:  
            expect(element.doubleFilesindicator.isPresent()).toBe(false);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes, I've already done that. Problem is I don't want test to fail. I want to check if double files icon isPresent(true) => click on it and expect list of copies is displayed;And if Double files icon isPresent(false) => expect list of copies is not displayed. Suppose there are too many assertions in one test case and it cant be done. But thanks for answer

Comment: well then change the `done.fail()` to `expect(element.doubleFilesindicator.isDisplayed()).toBe(false);` ?

Comment: Did that also. But it fails because it can't find element doubleFIlesIcon.

Comment: makes sense because the element needs to be present in the DOM if you want to use `isDisplayed()`  
What do you want to test if the `dubleFilesIcon` is NOT present? you can do a `expect(element.doubleFilesindicator.isPresent()).toBe(false);`

Comment: I agree. But if I use isPresent().toBe(false): Error: Timeout - Async callback... I think main problem is assumption of test case: If doubleFilesIcon is NOT displayed expect that indicator for double files is NOT displayed. And if doubleFilesIcon IS displayed, click on it and expect that indicator IS displayed. That test case simply cant fail. And that is problem. But you did help me a lot. As begginer isDisplayed() and  isPresent() were same to me. You cleared it out. Thank you again. I owe you coffee for that knowledge :)

Comment: then why you dont just simply log some text if the dubleFilesIcon is not present?  
also isDisplayed != isPresent

Comment: That's what I did eventually. Maybe I'll try to put two: it should {} blocks under if statement: if doubleFilesIcon isPresent {it should click} else{ it should expect element isDisplayed(false)}

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I've manged to do it: just added done.call() in else block. It is working. Not sure how, but it does:

```html
it('should check if assignment has double files', (done) => {
    element.dubleFilesIcon.isPresent().then(function(present) {
        if (present) {
            console.log('There ARE double files for this assignment!!!');
            assignmentHeader.doubleFiles();
            expect(element.doubleFilesindicator.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
            done();
        } else {
            done.call(expect(element.doubleFilesindicator.isPresent().toBe(false));)
        }
    });

});
```